# Elasticsearch matching on exact float value

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to match an exact value for a float in a filter. Consider `myfloat` in this filter:

```
{
  "filter" : { "bool" : { "must" : [
    { "match" : { "thing1" : "ABC" } },
    { "match" : { "thing2" : "SOMECODE" } },
    { "match" : { "myfloat" : 6490.1 } }
  ] } },
  "weight" : 10
}
```

However, it seems to disregard everything after the decimal. In other words, a record where myfloat is 6490.5 will match.

Is there a way to make it match only on an exact match? These are dollar values, so never more than two decimals.

EDIT:

Here's what ES says is the datatype:

```
"myfloat" : {
    "type" : "long"
},
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted the mapping. I'm guessing that the mapping for `myfloat` is  of type `string` and not `double` and the standard analyzer which is the default for strings  while indexing is removing the decimal part.  It should work if you  change the mapping to [double](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html)

Comment: Ah, interesting. Just googled an learned how to. Updating...

Comment: @keety - updated with actual data type for that field. What you say may still apply.

Comment: you would need to change the mapping type to double and reindex. By default for long type  the [coerce](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/coerce.html) flag is `true`  which truncates the decimal part .

Comment: @keety - thanks, I'll try that

Answer (score -1):

You should use "term" for exact match (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-term-query.html)
So your filter is going to become

```
{
  "filter" : { "bool" : { "must" : [
    { "match" : { "thing1" : "ABC" } },
    { "match" : { "thing2" : "SOMECODE" } },
    { "term" : { "myfloat" : 6490.1 } }
  ] } },
  "weight" : 10
}
```

Comment: No, term has the same problem.